# Faces with Seam3

Tags: jboss, seam, java-ee-6, cdi, seam3

i'm having 1 `Entity` with 1 `Named` Bean with `ConversationScope`, I created a `jsf form` with save button, and my problem is, why when my form are posted my entity with @injected, the properties of the entity bean(ArticuloController property) has not been injected. Exists with cdi something similar to `@in` annotation of seam2 to populate `@inject` `Entity entity`.

this is my source code:

```
@Entity
@Named("articulo")

public class Articulo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "articulo_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "articulo_seq", sequenceName = "articulo_seq")
    private Integer articulo;

    private String descripcion="";

//my action class

@Named("articuloController")
@ConversationScoped

public class ArticuloController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Articulo articulo;

    @Inject
private Messages messages;


@Begin
public String init() {
    messages.info("init conversation");
    //this values is not show in the jsf form
    articulo.setDescripcion("complete descripcion");
    articulo.setPrecio(new BigDecimal(0));
    return null;
}

public String save() {
        //the values of the properties is not the values filled by user, 
        //but is the values filled by init method
        System.out.println("save!" + articulo.getDescripcion()
            + articulo.getPrecio() + " " + id);

    return null;
}

my jsf page is


<f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{articuloController.id}" />
            <s:viewAction action="#{articuloController.init}" />
        </f:metadata>
        <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="panel">


            <h:outputLabel value="Descripcion" />

            <h:inputText value="#{articulo.descripcion}" id="descripcion"
                required="true" label="Descripción" />

            <rich:message for="descripcion" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Precio" />

            <h:inputText value="#{articulo.precio}" id="precio" required="true"
                label="Precio" />

            <rich:message for="precio" />

            <h:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{articuloController.save}" />

        </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Updated: i'm using seam3 3.1.0.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing JPA and CDI this way is a very bad idea. Things will not save correctly if you do it this way and you'll have exceptions all over the place. What you need to do is remove the @Name from entity and create a producer for it. You'll also need to add a scope annotation to the producer, probably request or conversation will work fine.

Comment: i remove ``named`` attribute from Entity bean, and i add a method createArticulo with ``@produces`` ``@named("articulo")``and ``@conversationScoped``, works fine to retrieve and populate ``@injected`` Articulo. but when i call my entityManager.persist(articulo) my object are not package.Articulo else my reference articulo apointer to $Proxy Object.. is a good work this? thanks